# How to provide AppleScript support to 'make new' element with one of its own elements

Tags: makefile, command, applescript

I am using the 'newScriptingObjectOfClass…' method within my application delegate's class in order to accommodate core data. I can 'make' the container element 'level' just fine, however I haven't a clue how to 'make' the element with one of its own elements. In order to make a new 'unit'--an element of 'levels'--I have to refer back at the containing 'level', which is circular logic.

Here's what seems to be the right way to create my new level, however the 'make' command does not provide the term 'element' as a parameter term for 'level' element, 'unit'.

```
tell application "SpellAnalysis"

     make new level with make new element unit  

end tell
```

Here's what my 'sdef' file shows:

> level n : Application levels collection
>
> elements
>   contains units; contained by application.
>
> unit n [inh. level] : Level's unit collection  syn unit
>
> elements
>   contains sections; contained by levels.

Also noteworthy is that my KVC method is never called from the 'newScriptObjectClass…' method when I successfully make a new 'level' (without a contained 'unit'):

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)entry inLevelObjectsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This compiled for me:

```
tell application "SpellAnalysis"

    ((make new level with «class») make new element with unit) // syntax 1

    ((make new level in class) make new unit with element) // syntax 2
```

end tell

```
    end tell
```

you'll likely need to tweak it a bit, but that's the general idea for syntax. when i tried your example i got:

> 'expected “into”, variable name, class name, other parameter name or
>   property but found command name.'

Comment: Thanks, Joe, for your response. There can't be many out there that are willing to wade into the esoteric topic of AppleScript support. I tried your suggested AppleScript commands with many variations and nothing quite works. My best attempt was:                          tell application "SpellAnalysis"
 
 set thisLevel to make new level with properties {level number:1}
 
 make new unit in thisLevel with properties {unit number:1}
 
end tell

Comment: I keep getting the AS error message: error "SpellAnalysis got an error: Invalid key form."  At this point, I believe there must be something wrong with my sdef oganization or perhaps the way my classes are specified.